# install new light on existing switch

Tags: electrical

I have a switch that goes to one overhead light.  on the switch is 1 line and the white and black wires are attached.  can I splice in to the line and run a black and white wire to the existing switch and then take the second wire attaching the two white wires together one from the splice and one from the new light and then take the black wire from the light and the wire from the splice to the new light switch.

Comment: Are you trying to add just a new light (two lights on the existing switch) or a whole new light and switch using the feed off the existing circuit?   Depending on that answer would also need to now where the feed wires is in the circuit (at the existing light or the existing switch)

Comment: I am adding a new light and switch.  the switch only has one wire going to the switch. that only goes to one light my guess is the fee wire is at the light

Answer (score 1):

If the switch has only the traveler wires, with the feed in the light then you basically do not have a neutral at the switch.  So a second switch can not be added at that location with out adding a neutral.  At the light the feed can be "tapped" hot and neutral and ran to a new light with a new traveler to the new switch.

Comment: that is what I thought i would have to do..... I was hoping not... thank you for the answer